# Check Box is Not Working As I Want It To Work

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

When I check the checkbox there is a timer in the text field that runs for 5 seconds, after the 5 seconds text field gets enabled for typing. Everything is fine at this moment but when I uncheck the checkbox within 5 seconds, it still gets enabled. I want that when I uncheck the check box, it should not enable.

Below is the code:

```
<html class='v2' dir='ltr' lang='en-us'>
<head lang="en">
<meta content='en_US' property='og:locale'/>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport'/>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="custom" name="custom" class="input_custom" placeholder="Enable Text" disabled 
style="height: 50px;width: 400px;">

<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" id="myonoffswitch" onclick="toggless()" 
style="height: 20px;width: 20px;">

<script>
function toggless() {
        if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
            Timess();
}
else {
    document.getElementById('custom').value = ''
    document.getElementById('custom').placeholder = 'Enable Text'
    document.getElementById('custom').disabled = true
    }}
    
function Timess(){
  var timeleft = 5;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
  document.getElementById("custom").placeholder = timeleft + 
  " "+"Seconds Remaining Enable Text";
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked
      document.getElementById('custom').placeholder = 'Enter Your Text'
      document.getElementById('custom').disabled = false
      }}, 1000);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with setInterval object that doesn't cleared when you uncheck the checkbox so you should clear it immediately whenever you want it to stop.

```html
<html class='v2' dir='ltr' lang='en-us'>

<head lang="en">
  <meta content='en_US' property='og:locale' />
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="custom" name="custom" class="input_custom" placeholder="Enable Text" disabled style="height: 50px;width: 400px;">

  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" id="myonoffswitch" onclick="toggless()" style="height: 20px;width: 20px;">

  <script>
    function toggless() {
      if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
        Timess();
      } else {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById('custom').value = ''
        document.getElementById('custom').placeholder = 'Enable Text'
        document.getElementById('custom').disabled = true
      }
    }
    var downloadTimer = null;

    function Timess() {
      var timeleft = 5;
      downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
        document.getElementById("custom").placeholder = timeleft +
          " " + "Seconds Remaining Enable Text";
        timeleft -= 1;
        if (timeleft <= 0) {
          clearInterval(downloadTimer);
          document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked
          document.getElementById('custom').placeholder = 'Enter Your Text'
          document.getElementById('custom').disabled = false
        }
      }, 1000);
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Waseem Almoliky solution, I see an issue with counter display. It starts with a second delay and exits immediately after 2sec(without showing 1sec), That's handled too.

```js
function toggless() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    Timess();
  } else {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
     clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById('custom').value = ''
    document.getElementById('custom').placeholder = 'Enable Text'
    document.getElementById('custom').disabled = true
  }
}
var downloadTimer = null;

function Timess() {
  var timeleft = 5;
  updateCounter();
  downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
    timeleft -= 1;
    updateCounter();
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked
      document.getElementById('custom').placeholder = 'Enter Your Text'
      document.getElementById('custom').disabled = false
    }
  }, 1000);
  
  function updateCounter() {
        document.getElementById("custom").placeholder = timeleft +
      " " + "Seconds Remaining Enable Text";
  } 
};
```

```html
<html class='v2' dir='ltr' lang='en-us'>

<head lang="en">
  <meta content='en_US' property='og:locale' />
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="custom" name="custom" class="input_custom" placeholder="Enable Text" disabled style="height: 50px;width: 400px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" id="myonoffswitch" onclick="toggless()" style="height: 20px;width: 20px;">
</body>

</html>
```